# get the last row in the db

Tags: codeigniter

What is the correct way to retrieve the last row, sorted desc by id, in CodeIgniter? 
I've tried `select_max` but I want the whole row.

```
function getLastPagination(){
    $data = array();
    $this->db->query("SELECT id,sort FROM pagination GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $query = $this->db->get('pagination');
    $data = $query->row_array();
    return $data;
}


$data['allpag'] = $this->Model_cats->getLastPagination();
$data['pagin'] = $data['allpag']['sort'];
$per_page = $data['pagin'];
```

Here I am getting the first value, but I want the last row.

Comment: are you getting some error or if not what is the output you are getting?

Comment: well i am trying to use a value from the last row... and it retrieves me the first value! i've added some edits to the post

Comment: How many rows are there totally if you didn't keep limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.............

```
function getLastPagination(){

     $query ="select * from pagination order by id DESC limit 1";

     $res = $this->db->query($query);

     if($res->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $res->result("array");
    }
    return array();
    }
}
```

In controller function you need to do following things.......

```
$allpag = $this->Model_cats->getLastPagination();
$per_page = $allpag[0]['sort'];
```

Comment: Message: Undefined index: sort :-?? that is my field name

Comment: do one thing before assigning $allpag['sort'] to $per_pag just do this and paste here what you get $print_r($allpag);

Comment: i am getting it right Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 130 [sort] => 12 ) )

Comment: k see the updated code and it works perfectly now please upvote and accept it as answer.....

Answer (score 9):

```
$this->db->select('id')->order_by('id','desc')->limit(1)->get('table_name')->row('id');
```

Comment: this solution is the winner

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pagination ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->row_array();
```

Should work?